# Error on TryUpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an error with TryUpdateModel when the field doesn't have a value and it's not nullable in the database.  If I change the field in the database to nullable, it works.  Anybody know a fix to get this to work with non nullable fields?  I'm new to MVC, so I'm just playing with a tutorial to try to understand it....

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form)
    {
        var movieToAdd = new Movies();

        if (Request != null && Request.Form != null && Request.Form.HasKeys() && ValueProvider == null)
        {
            ValueProvider = new FormCollection(Request.Form).ToValueProvider();
        }

        //Deserialize (Include white list!)
        TryUpdateModel(movieToAdd, new string[] { "Title", "Director" }, form.ToValueProvider());

        // Validate
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieToAdd.Title))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Title is required!");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieToAdd.Director))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Director", "Director is required!");

        // If valid, save movie to database
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.AddToMovies1(movieToAdd);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // Otherwise, reshow form
        return View(movieToAdd);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would change.

1. Modify your method signature to accept the strongly typed model that your `ActionResult` is expecting. From there you can check if the Model is valid or not and continue with saving to the database
2. Use strongly typed models and data annotations for validating your model

EG:

Create a model which you would use for the form Get And Post actions:

```
public class YourModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Title {get; set;]

    [Required]
    public string Director {get; set;}

}
```

Your Post ActionResult then becomes:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Add(YourModel postedform)
{
    // If valid, save movie to database
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.AddToMovies1(postedform);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Otherwise, reshow form
    return View(postedform);
}
```

Comment: I already created an edmx file so I can use Linq to Entities.  That already has the get and set functions for the properties.....That's all I should need, right?